# Where to store android application configuration to survive un/reinstall

Tags: android, configuration

I have an application which requires a large number of files to maintain user preferences and system configuration (this is a port from an existing project). I would like to know the preferred location to store this directory of configuration on an android device.

getExternalFilesDir() would appear to be a good choice, except that this directory is deleted if the application is uninstalled or reinstalled. This would be fine for a final uninstall, but if I provide my clients with an update to the application I need their preferences to be kept.

so somewhere in getFilesDir() is my next candidate, but where should I keep my configuration directory? just in the root of getFilesDir() in /Android? or someother 'toplevel' directory. This location has the advantage that the files would be preserved over a re-installation but I would then need to provide a way to delete the configuration on un-install, but this does not appear to possible as there does not seem to be an "onUninstall()" method.

(Imagine a RAW photo app which stored user settings for each picture; where would these settings get stored so that an update to the app didn't delete all the settings, but they would get deleted on uninstall?)

To add a slight twist to this, I need to be able to supply additional "package" applications to add files into this configuration directory -- so these must be able to be find the main application's config directory and to read and write files there. (i.e. it can't be private)

For development I'm just using getFilesDir() + "/MyApp" which works for now, but does not seem right!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> This would be fine for a final uninstall, but if I provide my clients with an update to the application I need their preferences to be kept.

`getExternalFilesDir()` is kept during an ordinary upgrade. The only time it will be removed is on an uninstall, "final" or otherwise. Upgrading an app does not normally involve an uninstall.

> so somewhere in getFilesDir() is my next candidate

`getFilesDir()` has the same characteristics as does `getExternalFilesDir()` with respect to upgrades and uninstalls.

> This location has the advantage that the files would be preserved over a re-installation

No, it does not. `getFilesDir()` and all locations in your app's [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) are removed upon an uninstall.

> Imagine a RAW photo app which stored user settings for each picture; where would these settings get stored so that an update to the app didn't delete all the settings, but they would get deleted on uninstall?

`getFilesDir()` would be a likely candidate.

> I need to be able to supply additional "package" applications to add files into this configuration directory -- so these must be able to be find the main application's config directory and to read and write files there. (i.e. it can't be private)

I strongly encourage you to use IPC (e.g., `ContentProvider`, `Service`, broadcast `Intent`), rather than manipulating an app's files behind its back, not only for app stability, but for better security. You can use Android's permissions system to mediate IPC, for example.

You are welcome to put files on external storage, which any app can get to, including most of the 1.2+ million apps on the Play Store and most malware apps ever written.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, and I will have a look at IPC once I've got the fundamentals working. Is there a suggested structure for files on external storage? rather than just /sdcard/MyApp? Should I at least conform to something like /sdcard/Applications/MyApp?